# Azure Timer trigger finction Dependency Injection issue

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

My Timer azure Function uses a default DI. It runs normally locally and in Azure using Code+Test - Test/Run.
But when it triggers by timer it fails with NullReferenceException on the injected property.

**function.json:**

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-3.0.11",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "schedule": "0 0 12 * * *",
      "useMonitor": true,
      "runOnStartup": false,
      "name": "myTimer"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/MyFunction.dll",
  "entryPoint": "MyFunctionApp.MyFunction.RunAsync"
}
```

**Function:**

```
 private readonly IMyService _myService;
 public MyFunction(IMyService myService)
 {
     _myService= myService;
 }

 [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
 public async Task RunAsync(
    [TimerTrigger("0 0 12 * * *")]
    TimerInfo myTimer,
    ILogger log)
 { ... }
```

**Service:**

```
 private readonly IMyClient client;

 public MyService(IMyClient _client)
 {
     client = _client;
 }
...
MyServiceMethod()
{
   client.MyClientMethod() <== it fails here
}
```

**Startup:**

```
var myParams = ...;
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyClient, MyClient>(provider =>
{
   return new MyClient(myParams);
});

builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
```

.Net Core 3.1

Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions 1.1.0

Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 3.1.12

Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-3.0.11

Comment: are you using ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) method ?

Comment: I use void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder) from FunctionsStartup class.

Comment: are you using [assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))] attribute on top of your function startup class ?

Comment: @NAS yes. And I see configure() runs correctly.

Comment: @Xavr could you please show us the completed code for debugging purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after downdrage
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions 1.1.0 to 1.0.0